# Pad string to the left of a character

Tags: python

I have a float that is stored as a string:

`float1 = 638045.11`
`float2 = 638045.1`

I want to print this:

`float1 = 0000638045.11`
`float2 = 0000638045.1`

I've tried `zfill` but that pads the entire string. How can I pad only to the left of the decimal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `str.split` to spilt the string to the left and right parts then use `zfill` on the left part.

```
float1 = 638045.11 
float2 = 638045.1

sf11, sf12 = str(float1).split('.') # -> ['638045', '11']
sf21, sf22 = str(float2).split('.') # -> ['638045', '1']

print(f"{sf11.zfill(10)}.{sf12}")
print(f"{sf21.zfill(10)}.{sf22}")
```

Output:

```
0000638045.11
0000638045.1
```

Comment: right on, I was hoping there was a built-in method, but this does the trick. Thank you!

Comment: @MikeMann, you're welcome. but I can say `zfill` add zeros to the string, for this reason, you need to spilt the string to the left and right part as you like.